# How to find an element with a specific attribute that has a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do a find an element which has the attribute "question-id" and equals a specific value?
From there, i need to find the closest div (the wrapper of this element).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('[question-id="yourvalue"]').closest('div');
```

Comment: And what if there’s no specific attributes ? I mean, that `question-id`can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [Attribute Equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector and the [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

```
var wrapper = $("[question-id='yourValue']").closest("div");
```

As an aside, note that you can use an [HTML5 data attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) (e.g. `data-question-id`) to embed information in your element without putting the validity of your markup in jeopardy. In that case, the code above would become:

```
var wrapper = $("[data-question-id='yourValue']").closest("div");
```