# How to get text() by attr() in jquery

Tags: jquery

Here's the questions

```
<div class="question">
            <div class="button" data-q="1" data-a="1"><a href="javascript:void();">2002</a></div>
            <div class="button" data-q="1" data-a="2" data-g="true"><a href="javascript:void();">2010</a></div>
            <div class="button" data-q="1" data-a="3"><a href="javascript:void();">1985</a></div>
            <div class="button" data-q="1" data-a="4"><a href="javascript:void();">2013</a></div>
        </div>
```

I would like to have the text() value for the attr() that have data-g set.

Right now the code I tried don't work

```
$('.question .button a').click(function(){    
  var aText = $(this).parents('.question').find('data-g').text();
  return aText;
});
```

I've tried this one but I get all text inside the .question DIV (2002,2010,1985,2013)

```
$('.question .button a').click(function(){    
  var aText = $(this).parents('.question').text();
  return aText;
});
```

So how can I have only the result of the DIV with data-g attribute and get only the 2010 as text.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value) and [How to find an element with a specific attribute that has a specific value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307448/how-to-find-an-element-with-a-specific-attribute-that-has-a-specific-value) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+find+element+with+certain+attribute).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.question .button a').click(function() {
    var aText = $(this).closest(".question").find("[data-g]").text();
                      // to check for `true` use ("[data-g='true']")
    console.log(aText);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2ny7j/

Comment: I've tried and didn't worked but this one did work: var aText = $(this).parents('.question').find("[data-g='true']").text(); - I have to go back to the parents first to find the closest. Well I think

Comment: @Warface You'd better use `closest` instead of `parents`. So you go to the first parent that has class `".question"` and then inside this element you search for elements with attribute `"[data-g]"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like

```
$('.question .button a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();    
  var aText = $(this).closest('.question').find("div[data-g]").text();
  alert(aText);
  return aText;
});​
```

**NOTE**

Returning `aText` from that function will return that value to nowhere in your code, as that is a callback function, more ever returning values from click callback have different meaning in jQuery, which may result in unexpected behavior. If you need to pass that value to somewhere else you have to call another function with this value like

```
someFunction(aText);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/2ny7j/1/)

Check jQuery [`has attribute selector`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)